# Background Image for SVG File

Tags: svg, png, background-image

I am trying to make a program that lets the user design their own Heraldic Logo.  Each part is layered using the Z-Index.  I've made over 100 assets the user can choose between.  At the moment I have them all in png form, which can allow me to make them specific colours, but I'd rather use background images in order to allow hatching (the old way to depict colour when you only had paper and black ink).
Is there a way that I can give an svg file a background image, or possibly even a png?  I'm 99% sure the png can't, but ever answer I've found about svg's says I'll need to remake them in the code (and I've already spent days making these assets twice).  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT (Code included)
In the head, I have each layer of the z-index named.

```
.field {
 background-image: url(img1.png);
 z-index: -8;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px; }

.party {
 background-image: url(img2.png);
 z-index: -7;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px; }

.shape {
 background-image: url(img3.png);
 z-index: 0;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px; }
```

Then in the  are things like this:

```
<object id="Field" class="Field" data="data1.svg"></object>
<object id="Party" class="Party" data="data2.svg"></object>
<object id="Shape" class="Shape" data="data3.svg"></object>
```

The class allows its position to be determined, and hopefully its background image.  The ID lets the script change the shape and background image.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. 1. inline svg elements can take a background. 2. Inside svg you can use the `<image>` element if you need to add images like png. 3. elements inside an svg element can't be layered using z-index.

Comment: How would I use your first and second points?   Currently I have several <object> which are all kept at the same location (0,0) which are controlled via the z-index.  The goal is to make one object take on a specific svg file's shape and fill it with a png image.

Comment: 1. svg { background: whatever; } 2. <svg ...>...<image href="your.png"/>...</svg> As for the rest of your comment: please edit your question and add all the details so that people at SO can help you.